# How to retrieve a list of arrays with specific column value?

Tags: php

Suppose I have an array with those values:

```
$arr = [
     ['type' => 'gallery', 'value' => 'foo'],
     ['type' => 'gallery', 'value' => 'foo2'],
     ['type' => 'gallery', 'value' => 'foo3'],
     ['type' => 'featured', 'value' => 'test'],
];
```

I need to find all `gallery` occurrences, so I did:

```
$key = array_search('gallery', array_column($arr, 'type'));
if($arr[$key] !== false)
{
   var_dump($arr[$key]);
}
```

but this print just one occurence:

> ['type' => 'gallery', 'value' => 'foo3'],

Comment: Look into [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

Comment: currently you just search the array for a key with type = gallery - there's 3 results found, the last iteration being the one saved - use array_filter to get an array of results rather than a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic array filtering problem. And the provided solution is just one of many possible solutions.

```
$arr = [
    ['type' => 'gallery', 'value' => 'foo'],
    ['type' => 'gallery', 'value' => 'foo2'],
    ['type' => 'gallery', 'value' => 'foo3'],
    ['type' => 'featured', 'value' => 'test'],
];

// filter out other types. make sure only 'gallery' types are returned to the new array $arrOnlyGallery.
// You can use a for loop too here.
$arrOnlyGallery = array_filter($arr, function($a) {
   return $a['type'] == 'gallery';
});

// show the array which should only contain 'gallery' types.
var_dump($arrOnlyGallery);
```

**Output:**

> array(3) { [0]=> array(2) { ["type"]=> string(7) "gallery" ["value"]=>
>   string(3) "foo" } [1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)=> array(2) { ["type"]=> string(7) "gallery"
>   ["value"]=> string(4) "foo2" } [2]=> array(2) { ["type"]=> string(7)
>   "gallery" ["value"]=> string(4) "foo3" } }

You can read more about PHP array filtering [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $arr = [
     ['type' => 'gallery', 'value' => 'foo'],
     ['type' => 'gallery', 'value' => 'foo2'],
     ['type' => 'gallery', 'value' => 'foo3'],
     ['type' => 'featured', 'value' => 'test'],
];



$new = array_filter($arr, function ($var) {
    return $var['type'] == 'gallery';
});
echo "<pre>";
print_r($new);
```

*Edit: If it needs to be interchangeable, you can modify the code slightly:*

```
$filterBy = 'gallery'; // or Finance etc.

$new = array_filter($arr, function ($var) use ($filterBy) {
    return ($var['type'] == $filterBy);
});
```

**output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => gallery
            [value] => foo
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => gallery
            [value] => foo2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [type] => gallery
            [value] => foo3
        )

)
```

Comment: This isn't quite right, because `$value` will never just be the string `gallery`. For simple samples like this, it's helpful to run them yourself to double-check them before posting, e.g. using this tool: https://3v4l.org/QC8a0

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function getGallery($var)
  {
  return($var['type'] == 'gallery');
  }

  $arr = [
     ['type' => 'gallery', 'value' => 'foo'],
     ['type' => 'gallery', 'value' => 'foo2'],
     ['type' => 'gallery', 'value' => 'foo3'],
     ['type' => 'featured', 'value' => 'test'],
  ];

$filteredArr = array_filter($arr,"getGallery");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do simply array_filter and it will give expected result.

```
$searchResult =  array_filter($arr, function($v, $k) {
    return $v['type'] == "gallery";
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);

print_r($searchResult);`
```